# How to add from & to date filter in magento script?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order

Here is what i have tried

```
 $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
    $orderItem->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id')
        ->where("order.created_at >= ?" AND "order.created_at <= ?", '2020-08-23' , '2020-08-25');

print_r(array_unique($orderids));
```

I am not getting proper data using the above code for "from & to" filter,

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
$fromDate = "XXXXX";
$toData = "XXXXXX"
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$toDate));
$orderIds = [];
foreach ($orders as $order) {           
    
    $items = $orderId->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemPrice = $item->getPrice();
        $itemSku = $item->getSku();
        $itemId = $item->getProductId();
        if(!itemSku && !itemId){
          $orderids[]  = $order->getId();
        }
    }
}

print_r($orderids);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have to implement filter with $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
    $orderItem->getSelect()
        ->joinInner(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id')

Comment: At end you want to get orderids then no need to filter order item.

Comment: but i have to  use filter for order item as well that's why i am using that code

Comment: I am trying to fetch order id that have order items with blank sku & product id from table That's why i am using the code which is mentioned in this question.

Comment: Check my updated ans

Comment: Thankyou but this is not correct approach, because i have many orders & products. so using the answer which you have posted will cause performance issue.